# Django Admin Inline - same UUID being generated for primary key

Tags: django, django-admin

When I click on "add new button" in django admin to add another inline item. UUID field (primary key) is same for all inlines. see following gif:

```
# Models
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Question(CommonModel):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
        Subject, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='questions')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='questions', null=True, blank=True)


class AnswerChoice(CommonModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answer_choices')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='answer_choices', null=True, blank=True)
    is_correct_answer = models.BooleanField()


# admin code
class AnswerChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AnswerChoice
    extra = 0
    fields = [
        'id',
        'text',
        'image',
        'is_correct_answer',
    ]
    formset = AnswerChoiceInlineFormSet

    def get_formset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = super().get_formset(*args, **kwargs)
        formset.form.base_fields['id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        return formset


class QuestionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        text = cleaned_data.get('text')
        image = cleaned_data.get('image')
        has_text_or_image = bool(text or image)

        if not has_text_or_image:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Question should have either text or image specified.")
```

[image]

Comment: please add your models code for more info